# Как отобразить часы правильно в таймере

Tags: javascript, jquery

Кто знает как вывести правильное количество часов, в диапазоне 24 часов на js? Я могу вывести все часы, но что то не соображу как вывести только от 1-24. Кто знает, подскажите плз...

```js
function timerLeft() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var daysLeft = document.getElementById('days'),
      hoursLeft = document.getElementById('hours'),
      minLeft = document.getElementById('min'),
      secLeft = document.getElementById('sec'),
      dateNow = new Date().getTime(),
      dateFinish = new Date(2018, 07, 05),
      sec = Math.floor((dateFinish - dateNow) / 1000),
      secToMinutes = sec % 3600,
      daysNumber = Math.floor(sec / 86400),
      hoursNumber = Math.floor(sec / 3600),
      minutesNumber = Math.floor(secToMinutes / 60),
      secondsNumber = secToMinutes % 60;

    daysLeft.innerHTML = daysNumber;
    hoursLeft.innerHTML = hoursNumber;
    minLeft.innerHTML = minutesNumber;
    secLeft.innerHTML = secondsNumber;

  })
}
timerLeft();
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="clock">
    <div id="days"></div>
    <div id="hours"></div>
    <div id="min"></div>
    <div id="sec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же уже знаете про оператор `%`:

```
hoursNumber = Math.floor(sec / 3600) % 24,
```

Comment: Это работает. Спасибо! А можете детально расписать как эта строчка работает, а то я не понял

Comment: До меня дошло, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: это Ваша строчка с добавленным вычислением остатка от деления на 24